# Windows 8 app with sql database .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); gets hung up after successfull completion

Tags: c#, sql, windows-store-apps, async-await

Just as the title states the code is getting hung up right here>>>

```
ds.running.Create(r).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

In the database I can see that the sql command has been completed successfully but the program itself has not moved on from that point and is still waiting for the GetResult() command. Did I implement the .GetResult wrong or what did I do wrong??

Here is the step in results too to understand exactly what is going on in each command:

1st step in:

```
public async Task<int> Create(T newEntity)
    {
        return await db.InsertAsync(newEntity);
    }
```

2nd step in:

```
public Task<int> InsertAsync (object item)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
            var conn = GetConnection ();
            using (conn.Lock ()) {
                return conn.Insert (item);
            }
        });
    }
```

3rd step in: goes back to step in 1... and it just stays there for all the rest of the time the app runs....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you should never call `GetAwaiter()` yourself, you should just use `await`.

What you're running into is the [classical deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) caused by synchronously waiting for an `async` method. Calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` behaves the same as `.Wait()` in this regard.

Comment: So I should replace .GetAwaiter().GetResult() with .Wait()

Comment: @wizage No. If you do that, your code will behave the same as it does now, i.e. it will deadlock. You should replace it with `await`. If you absolutely need to block, use `Wait()` and also use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for all `await`s in the method you're calling and the methods it calls, etc. and then use `Wait()`.

Comment: Ok for some reason .Await , .await are not available for me to use after my .Create(r)
All that I can do is this list:
.AsAsyncAction
.AsAsynchOperation<>
.AsyncState
.ConfigureAwait
.ContinueWith
.ContinueWith<>
.CreationOptions
.Equals
.Exception
.GetAwaiter
.GetHashCode
.GetType
.Id
.IsCanceled
.IsCompleted
.IsFaulted
.Result
.RunSynchronously
.Start
.Status
.ToString
.Wait

Comment: @wizage `await` is not a method on `Task`, it's a keyword. And you're already using it your code, so I assumed you know how to do it: it's `await someTask`.